# Centering matrix

Tags: matrices, center

Does anyone know how to center the following matrix? (eq. 3.7.14)
and how to add a space between the elements of the vector (eq. 3.7.13)?

```
\begin{equation}\label{3.7.13}
{\vec{T}_{1}}^\intercal=[T_{a} && T_{1}&T_{2} & \cdots & T_{N-1}  & T_{N} & T_{b}] 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{3.7.14}
\mathbf{A}_{1}=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
-h_{a}S & h_{a}S               &0            &\Cdots  & & &0 \\
h_{a}S  & -h_{a}S-\alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,2} & \Cdots & && 0 \\
0       & \alpha_{1,2}         & -\alpha_{1,2}-\alpha_{2,3}& \alpha_{2,3} & \Cdots && 0\\
\Vdots      & \Vdots   &\Ddots &\Ddots & &&\Vdots\\
0&0& \Cdots & \alpha_{N-2,N-1} & -\alpha_{N-2,N-1}-\alpha_{N-1,N} &\alpha_{N-1,N}&0\\
0 &&& \Cdots & \alpha_{N-1,N} & h_{b}S-\alpha_{N-1,N}  & h_{b}S\\
0 & && \Cdots & & h_{b}S & -h_{b}S
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. You should provide a full MWE (minimal working example) with the `\documentclass`, the `\begin{document}`, the `\end{document}`, etc. We don't know the text width of your document...

Comment: It seems that your matrix is much wide than  `\textwidth`. You can reduce used font size, write nodes text in two lines (if this is acceptable) or make `\textwidth` locally wider (by use of `changepage` package.

Answer (score 2):

As on of possibilities, already mentioned in my comment, is locally increase text width:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}\label{3.7.13}
\vec{T}_{1}^\intercal
    =[T_{a} T_{1} T_{2} \cdots T_{N-1} T_{N} T_{b}]
\end{equation}
%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-4em}{-3em}
\begin{equation}\label{3.7.14}
\mathbf{A}_{1}=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
-h_{a}S & h_{a}S               &0            &\Cdots  & & &0 \\
h_{a}S  & -h_{a}S-\alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,2} & \Cdots & && 0 \\
0       & \alpha_{1,2}         & -\alpha_{1,2}-\alpha_{2,3}& \alpha_{2,3} & \Cdots && 0\\
\Vdots      & \Vdots   &\Ddots &\Ddots & &&\Vdots\\
0&0& \Cdots & \alpha_{N-2,N-1} & -\alpha_{N-2,N-1}-\alpha_{N-1,N} &\alpha_{N-1,N}&0\\
0 &&& \Cdots & \alpha_{N-1,N} & h_{b}S-\alpha_{N-1,N}  & h_{b}S\\
0 & && \Cdots & & h_{b}S & -h_{b}S
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```